# can't enable proper landscape mode on iOS with sencha touch 2 native build

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, sencha-touch-2, landscape-portrait

I am currently building a sencha touch 2 application and trying to deploy it on iPad. I am working on "mac OS Snow Leopard" and trying to deploy my app on an iPad2 with iOS 5.1.

After having some issues building and deploying the application, that I managed to fix thanks to this post: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?192946-2.0.1RC-Native-build-seem-to-be-broken ; I seem to have a new problem with orientation.

Indeed, even with a specific "landscapeLeft" orientation configuration given in my 'packager.json' file, both iOSSimulator and iOS launch the app in landscape mode, but as soon as the sencha logo is gone my view goes to portrait mode and get stuck in this mode. When I do an Ext.getOrientation() I get 'portrait' as an answer all the time, whatever the orientation of my device is. 
No exceptions or console messages are launched and after having visited a lot and a lot of posts I haven't found anything really addressing my issue. the closest one I found was this one: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?151238-landscape-gt-portrait-orientation-how-does-it-work-now, but with sadly no effect.

I'd also like to keep the native build of sencha and avoiding phonegap if possible.

has anyone encountered the issue, or have any idea on this problem? I am quite lost and need to fix the issue as quickly as possible.

Thanks.